# Why we use markup language ? especially in wiki engine

Tags: wiki, mediawiki

I like WYSIWYG, I don't like Markup Langage in Wiki engine.
Why we use it? what we gain?

Comment: I came to the conclusion that the MediaWiki markup is one nasty tar-pit of ill-structured unspecified php mess with millions of hard coded corner cases. It is so sad that is not even funny. The "dangerous html"-argument is bull****, we have high-powerd xml/html parser to handle this, what we dont have are proper grammars and parsers for the mediawiki "markup".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can filter out any potentially dangerous html tags, what remains cannot be executed in a database query or in an HTML output. Giving it out in an HTML page, you have full control of how the tags should be written.

Answer (score 0):

Avoidance against `cross site scripting issue` and other such related issue that can occur due to exposing all the complete HTML vocab

Answer (score 0):

They're a simple way to define data and usually easy to manipulate.